# Image src url not work with some image path

Tags: html, image

I am using below HTML code for showing image in my application.

```
<img src="../folder/subfolder/imagename" longdesc="description" alt="alt message">
```

Image name is fetching dynamic from database. It's work with all product detail page, but one of page image are not showing.
I have check in database and image folder, image is existing then why it's not showing for particular page?
This is link of page where image is not showing.

__http://www.worldoils.com/marketplace/equipdetails.php?id=333&Offshore+Research+Vessel+-+Ice+Class

Please any one explain this reason?

Thanks for your comment, It's some helpful to me.
I have notice one more thing, whenever i want to request for product detail page which name contain 'Research' keyword. it give me malware warning specifies adiccionradio.com

I search in database, no any records contain adiccionradio.com link.

Any one can explain what is happening with it??? For this some of my site page showing malware  warning.

Have any idea??

Thanks

Comment: I crippled the link that was provided because Chrome warned me about a potential source of malware. Sorry. Try posting a direct link to the image URL itself.

Comment: @Seema, I get a malware warning when I try to go to that link.

Comment: I am not getting any malware warning, image are showing with direct link but i want to know why indirect link not work for some of image path...?

Comment: Hello, Please check the another link. http://www.worldoils.com/marketplace/equipdetails.php?id=642&7040%20BHP%20AHTS%20-%20For%20Sale  Tell me if you found same warning. This page is showing images with indirect links.

Comment: @Semma, the second link you provided works fine. The first link is including content from a site that has been tagged as suspicious for spreading Malware. Specifically content from `adiccionradio` according to google.

Answer (score 0):

Seema

your image name has extension?
as you write `src="../folder/subfolder/imagename"`
is it something like `src="../folder/subfolder/imagename.jpg"`